# Setting of default when using add_column (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, migration

Usually when using add_column in a migration we have to set the default value by using :default => 0 OR :default => '' (if we add a string)

Is it possible to change the default add_column behaviour so that each time we add a column, if we add an integer, float etc 0 is set as default and if we add a string '' is set as the default?

Answer (score 1):

> Usually when using add_column in a migration we have to set the default value by using :default => 0 OR :default => '' (if we add a string)

As long as you don't set `null: false`, there is no requirement to add a default value.

The default is required only if you set `null: false` or if you want a default value to be set.

Moreover, the configuration also depends on the database. Some database engines, if you set `null: false` and you don't provide a default explicitly, will automatically use the default value for the specific data type which in general is

- `0` for integers
- empty string for strings
- `0.0` for floats
- `false` for boolean

Again, it depends on the database. At Rails level, there is no way to set a global default, nor to change the behavior of `add_column` (unless you override it... but that would be a bad decision).